# d3 Race chart - example with year converted to date

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm working with d3 js framework, and are trying to build a race chart to engage sales.
I've found an example which seems to be quite close.

The only difference is that it uses years instead of normale dates.

```
example data:
{
name: 'test'
value: 12,
year: 2017,
lastValue: 34,
rank: 5
}

My data:
{
initials: 'jaf'
value: 12,
act_date: 2023-03-11,
lastValue: 34,
rank: 5
}
```

This is the current code, which somewhat works if the test data is used, how do i convert it to function with my dataset?

````
function gen_chart(elm, url) {
var svg = d3.select(elm).append("svg")
  .attr("width", 960)
  .attr("height", 600);



var tickDuration = 250;

var top_n = 12;
var height = 600;
var width = 960;

const margin = {
   top: 80,
   right: 0,
   bottom: 5,
   left: 0
};

let barPadding = (height-(margin.bottom+margin.top))/(top_n*5);

let title = svg.append('text')
   .attr('class', 'title')
   .attr('y', 24)
   .html('Ekstern salg - Telenor');

let subTitle = svg.append("text")
   .attr("class", "subTitle")
   .attr("y", 55)
   .html("Siden 2015");

let caption = svg.append('text')
   .attr('class', 'caption')
   .attr('x', width)
   .attr('y', height-5)
   .style('text-anchor', 'end')
   .html('Kilde: Intern måling');

let year = 2000;

d3.json(url).then(function(data) {
   //if (error) throw error;

   console.log(data);

   data.forEach(d => {
      
      d.value = +d.value,
         d.lastValue = +d.lastValue,
         d.value = isNaN(d.value) ? 0 : d.value,
         d.year = +d.year,
         d.colour = d3.hsl(Math.random()*360,0.75,0.75)
   });

   console.log(data);

   let yearSlice = data.filter(d => d.year == year && !isNaN(d.value))
      .sort((a,b) => b.value - a.value)
      .slice(0, top_n);

   yearSlice.forEach((d,i) => d.rank = i);


   let x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(yearSlice, d => d.value)])
      .range([margin.left, width-margin.right-65]);

   let y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([top_n, 0])
      .range([height-margin.bottom, margin.top]);

   let xAxis = d3.axisTop()
      .scale(x)
      .ticks(width > 500 ? 5:2)
      .tickSize(-(height-margin.top-margin.bottom))
      .tickFormat(d => d3.format(',')(d));

   svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'axis xAxis')
      .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${margin.top})`)
      .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll('.tick line')
      .classed('origin', d => d == 0);

   svg.selectAll('rect.bar')
      .data(yearSlice, d => d.name)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'bar')
      .attr('x', x(0)+1)
      .attr('width', d => x(d.value)-x(0)-1)
      .attr('y', d => y(d.rank)+5)
      .attr('height', y(1)-y(0)-barPadding)
      .style('fill', d => d.colour);

   svg.selectAll('text.label')
      .data(yearSlice, d => d.name)
      .enter()
      .append('text')
      .attr('class', 'label')
      .attr('x', d => x(d.value)-8)
      .attr('y', d => y(d.rank)+5+((y(1)-y(0))/2)+1)
      .style('text-anchor', 'end')
      .html(d => d.name);

   svg.selectAll('text.valueLabel')
      .data(yearSlice, d => d.name)
      .enter()
      .append('text')
      .attr('class', 'valueLabel')
      .attr('x', d => x(d.value)+5)
      .attr('y', d => y(d.rank)+5+((y(1)-y(0))/2)+1)
      .text(d => d3.format(',.0f')(d.lastValue));

   let yearText = svg.append('text')
      .attr('class', 'yearText')
      .attr('x', width-margin.right)
      .attr('y', height-25)
      .style('text-anchor', 'end')
      .html(~~year)
      .call(halo, 10);

   let ticker = d3.interval(e => {

      yearSlice = data.filter(d => d.year == year && !isNaN(d.value))
         .sort((a,b) => b.value - a.value)
         .slice(0,top_n);

      yearSlice.forEach((d,i) => d.rank = i);


      x.domain([0, d3.max(yearSlice, d => d.value)]); 

      svg.select('.xAxis')
         .transition()
         .duration(tickDuration)
         .ease(d3.easeLinear)
         .call(xAxis);

      let bars = svg.selectAll('.bar').data(yearSlice, d => d.name);

      bars
         .enter()
         .append('rect')
         .attr('class', d => `bar ${d.name.replace(/\s/g,'_')}`)
         .attr('x', x(0)+1)
         .attr( 'width', d => x(d.value)-x(0)-1)
         .attr('y', d => y(top_n+1)+5)
         .attr('height', y(1)-y(0)-barPadding)
         .style('fill', d => d.colour)
         .transition()
         .duration(tickDuration)
         .ease(d3.easeLinear)
         .attr('y', d => y(d.rank)+5);

      bars
         .transition()
         .duration(tickDuration)
         .ease(d3.easeLinear)
         .attr('width', d => x(d.value)-x(0)-1)
         .attr('y', d => y(d.rank)+5);

      bars
         .exit()
         .transition()
         .duration(tickDuration)
         .ease(d3.easeLinear)
         .attr('width', d => x(d.value)-x(0)-1)
         .attr('y', d => y(top_n+1)+5)
         .remove();

      let labels = svg.selectAll('.label')
         .data(yearSlice, d => d.name);

      labels
         .enter()
         .append('text')
         .attr('class', 'label')
         .attr('x', d => x(d.value)-8)
         .attr('y', d => y(top_n+1)+5+((y(1)-y(0))/2))
         .style('text-anchor', 'end')
         .html(d => d.name)    
         .transition()
         .duration(tickDuration)
         .ease(d3.easeLinear)
         .attr('y', d => y(d.rank)+5+((y(1)-y(0))/2)+1);


      labels
         .transition()
         .duration(tickDuration)
         .ease(d3.easeLinear)
         .attr('x', d => x(d.value)-8)
         .attr('y', d => y(d.rank)+5+((y(1)-y(0))/2)+1);

      labels
         .exit()
         .transition()
         .duration(tickDuration)
         .ease(d3.easeLinear)
         .attr('x', d => x(d.value)-8)
         .attr('y', d => y(top_n+1)+5)
         .remove();



      let valueLabels = svg.selectAll('.valueLabel').data(yearSlice, d => d.name);

      valueLabels
         .enter()
         .append('text')
         .attr('class', 'valueLabel')
         .attr('x', d => x(d.value)+5)
         .attr('y', d => y(top_n+1)+5)
         .text(d => d3.format(',.0f')(d.lastValue))
         .transition()
         .duration(tickDuration)
         .ease(d3.easeLinear)
         .attr('y', d => y(d.rank)+5+((y(1)-y(0))/2)+1);

      valueLabels
         .transition()
         .duration(tickDuration)
         .ease(d3.easeLinear)
         .attr('x', d => x(d.value)+5)
         .attr('y', d => y(d.rank)+5+((y(1)-y(0))/2)+1)
         .tween("text", function(d) {
            let i = d3.interpolateRound(d.lastValue, d.value);
            return function(t) {
               this.textContent = d3.format(',')(i(t));
            };
         });


      valueLabels
         .exit()
         .transition()
         .duration(tickDuration)
         .ease(d3.easeLinear)
         .attr('x', d => x(d.value)+5)
         .attr('y', d => y(top_n+1)+5)
         .remove();

        
      yearText.html(~~year);

      let current_year = new Date();
      current_year = current_year.getFullYear();

      if(year == current_year) ticker.stop();
      year = d3.format('.1f')((+year) + 0.1);
   },tickDuration);

});

const halo = function(text, strokeWidth) {
   text.select(function() { return this.parentNode.insertBefore(this.cloneNode(true), this); })
      .style('fill', '#ffffff')
      .style('stroke','#ffffff')
      .style('stroke-width', strokeWidth)
      .style('stroke-linejoin', 'round')
      .style('opacity', 1);

}   
}

gen_chart("#v_stats", "test.json")```
````